# Matching substrings wíth strings of 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I was trying to write a Code for work when I encountered a problem. My goal is to find the businesses, that are located in a particular district.
I have two lists. The 1st list's items look like this "City Count Businessname" and contain all the cities in our county, whereas the second lists items look like this "City", and contain all the cities in our district. I want to compare these lists in order to get all the businesses in our district as a result like this "City Count Businessname".

That is my Code:

`jVal = "|".join(A)  print([i for i in B if i in jVal ])`

I also tried out this one:

```
for item1 in A:
for item2 in B:
    if item1 == item2:
        print(item1)
```

Both didn't work though and I either didn't get any result at all or get the whole of "A" as a result.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming that A and B are the two lists, why would you expect item1 to equal item2 in the second code fragment? Also, please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Can you give an example of the two lists and the desired output?

Comment: Hello there, thank you for all your help! Here are the 2 lists: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Hw3NnHZWgzhghPhh1d0eHyaxq6sKRmS?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You missed **indentation** for the inner **for** loop

```
for item1 in A:
  for item2 in B:
    if item1 == item2:
        print(item1)
```

or you can do this using `set` if the values in both list are single words

```
list(set(A).intersection(set(B)))
```

from your question its a combination of words in list

```
businesses = ["C1 count B1", "C2 count B2", "C1 count B3"]
cities = ["C1","C3","C4"]

for city in cities:
  for business in businesses:
    if city in business.split():
      print(city, business)
```

Comment: When would `item1 == item2` ever be True when the items in one list look like `"City Count Businessname"` and the items in the other look like `"City"`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer You are Right, I assumed its just cities. Updated the Answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help! None of the suggested techniques did work for me though. Here are the 2 lists if you would like to have a look at them: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Hw3NnHZWgzhghPhh1d0eHyaxq6sKRmS?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohannFlöck I took the files from shared derive, I have shared the complete solution, check my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961998/5858006

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand of your list contents, you can use something like this:

```
businesses = ["C1 count B1", "C2 count B2", "C1 count B3"]
cities = ["C1","C3","C4"]

output = [a for a in businesses if a.split()[0] in cities]
print(output)
```

Assuming spaces separate the components of each item in the first list, this produces:

```
['C1 count B1', 'C1 count B3']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! None of the suggested techniques did work for me though. Here are the 2 lists if you would like to have a look at them: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Hw3NnHZWgzhghPhh1d0eHyaxq6sKRmS?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

sory bruh here is da code you need (old version was not working beacuse of newlines-"\n"):

```
def pt(x):
    with open(x+".txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

b=pt("Businesses")
c=pt("Cities")

arr=[i for i in b if any(item in i.split() for item in c)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it didn't work though - here are the 2 lists if you want to have a look at them: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Hw3NnHZWgzhghPhh1d0eHyaxq6sKRmS?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
for local_city in list_of_cities_in_our_district:
  for entry in list_of_city_county_business:
    if entry's city matches local_city:
        print the business name
```

Here's some pseudocode that should do what you want... I leave the semantic details to you, for parsing the layout of the lists, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but none of the above did work. Do you think that it could have to do with my lists? Here are my lists, if oyu would like to have a look on them: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-Hw3NnHZWgzhghPhh1d0eHyaxq6sKRmS?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohannFlöck - Your cities text file looks fine, as long as you read it in, treating each line as a separate city and stripping off any leading/trailing white space.  The business list text file looks less compliant, but from what I can see, if you split each line into the first 25 characters and then the rest, you can strip leading/trailing white space for the first to get the city, and do the same for the latter to get the business name. You can also do a little smart post-processing to remove the count number if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Complete Solution, Needed a lot of **formatting** due to **unstructured data**.

```
with open("Businesses.txt", mode='r') as f:
    listBusinesses = f.readlines()
with open("Cities.txt", mode='r') as f:
        listCities = f.readlines()

Cities = []
for values in listCities:
    if len(values.split('\n')[0]) > 0:
        Cities.append(values.split('\n')[0])

CityNames = []
BusinessNames = []
SerialNo = []

for values in listBusinesses:
    if len(values.split('\n')[0]) > 0:

        vCityNames = values.split('\n')[0][:26].strip()
        CityNames.append(vCityNames)

        vSerialWithBusiness = values.split('\n')[0][26:].strip()
        if len(vSerialWithBusiness.split('\n')[0].split('.')) > 1:
            vSerialNo = (vSerialWithBusiness.split('\n')[0].split('.')[0].strip())
            SerialNo.append(vSerialNo)
            vBusinessNames = (vSerialWithBusiness.split('\n')[0].split('.')[1].strip())
        else:
            vBusinessNames = (vSerialWithBusiness.split('\n')[0].split('.')[0].strip())
            SerialNo.append('Missing')
        BusinessNames.append(vBusinessNames)

assert len(CityNames) == len(SerialNo) == len(BusinessNames)

count = 0
for x  in range(len(Cities)):
    for y in range(len(CityNames)):
        if Cities[x] == CityNames[y]:
            count = count + 1
        print(Cities[x].ljust(27,' ') ,SerialNo[y].ljust(7,' '), BusinessNames[y])

# Total Businesses 3488,  matching Cities 345
```

Comment: Hello there! Thank you so much for the code. However, it is strange that your results show "345 matching cities". When I am trying to run the code, I get thousands of businesses shown, matching with cities that aren't even the actual location of the businesses. What could be the possible problem with that? (I added encoding="utf-8" to the files)

Comment: @Anmol Parida I believe the print statement should be indented to produce the desired output - as it is, you're simply producing the cartesian product of the two lists. Also, you really need to add an encoding when reading text files. It is good that you are parsing each business record (even though this was not requested), but this could have been done more economically using a regular expression. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given the imperfectly-formatted data in the supplied data files, the following code might work better. It has the added advantage of grouping the result by city in the order the cities appear in the cities.txt file.

```
with open('Cities.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f: cities = f.read().split('\n')
cities = [x.strip() for x in cities if x]

with open('Businesses.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f: businesses = f.read().split('\n')
businesses = [x for x in businesses if x]

found = 0
for c in cities:
    for b in businesses:
        if b.startswith(c):
            found += 1
            print(b)

print(f'Found {found} businesses')
```

Comment: @JohannFlöck if this solution solves your question, kindly mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Given your data files, the following will do the trick. The code works on the assumption that the businesses file contains the name of the city within the first 27 characters of each line (some lines are actually missing the city!).

The code also filters out some blank lines in the data files.

```
with open('Cities.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f: cities = f.read().split('\n')
cities = [x.lower() for x in cities if x]

with open('Businesses.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f: businesses = f.read().split('\n')
businesses = [x for x in businesses if x]

for b in businesses:
    if b[:27].strip().lower() in cities: print(b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the code is working now. What do you think was the problem with the Code that I used, for it not to be able to give me the right result? Thank you and best regards.

Comment: @JohannFlöck Does this code show business for the city ```Wörgl, Galtür, Sölden, Lähn```. You need to be very careful if its production data. For certain cities the index starts from 26 and not 27 ```so you missed out a lot of cities ``` This will fetch the full result. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961998/5858006

Comment: @JohannFlöck the problem with the code you were using is that you were treating the items  in the list of businesses as though they were a single entity, when in fact each is made up of 3 components - City, Count and Business. So you must first extract the city from the business. Unfortunately, the business data file you supplied is not well-formed (for example in some lines the city is missing) -  for this code to work well you need to ensure that the data is correctly formatted, with the city column taking up at least 27 characters.

Comment: PS. This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63967093/10309040 might work better given the data files you supplied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The solution that you posted gave me 345 businesses, which is true I think. It has to work, cause it uses startswith, and every item of the "Businesses" list starts with a City.